# Is there an electromagnetic analogue of thermoacoustics?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, waves, acoustics

I've just learned about thermoacoustic heatpumps. My understanding is that a standing acoustic wave in a tube of gas produces areas of higher and lower average pressure which results in a gradient of temperature in the gas. This effect can be exploited to pump heat from certain areas to others.

What I'm wondering is if there's a similar effect with electromagnetic waves, and if it's exploited in practice for some engineering purpose. It seems to me that a standing EM wave would produce areas of higher and lower electrical potential and magnetic strength, but is this used for anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are describing a *waveguide* which is a pipe that is used to conduct microwaves. It is possible to build standing electromagnetic waves inside such a pipe, giving rise to the *klystron* and *magnetron* tubes, which use standing waves to create and amplify microwave radiation.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for!